# webmatrix - sql query relationship

Tags: sql, razor, webmatrix

I have two tables in my database, one with info on properties in my database, and one with all the images for those properties. The table layout looks like this.

**Property Table:**
PropertyID, 
PropertyName, 
PrimaryImage

**Images Table:**
PropertyID, 
ImageID, 
ImageURL

I want to show the primary image for each property. There may be many images with the same PropertyID, but I need to show the image that is specified in the PrimaryImage row, which is tied with an ImageID.

Here's my code so far:

```
var PropertyDetails = ("SELECT * from Property_Info");
@foreach(var row in qPropertyDetails){
    <h4>@row.PropertyName</h4>
    <img src="@row.PrimaryImageID" alt="">
}
```

But instead of the PrimaryImageID, I actually need the URL that it is tied to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to look into Sql join statements for an example you can look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

I guess your query should look something like this:

pseudo code:

```
SELECT * FROM 'Property Table' props LEFT JOIN 'Images Table' imgs ON imgs.PropertyID = props.PropertyID
```

Event better would be to add an foreign key to the joining table [more info about foreign keys](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

Comment: Ah, i've sorted it. I did try and use joins, but had no luck. Turns out i was joining on PropertyID (like in your example) which returns many rows, instead of joining on the foreign key. Many thanks, you've pointed me in the right direction.